# Apply luigi pipeline on multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, etl, luigi

I've got **scraped** data and would like to use luigi to process it. Actually I've got all transformations etc. And now I'm dealing with it how could I pass all my files to luigi pipeline.
I have external task that is returning filename with my scraped data that is called in list generated by glob. From each input file I'm getting cleaned and transformed output

Function is first step of my pipeline that I'm invoking pipeline like below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.build([l.Load()], local_scheduler=False)
```

```py
class ReadFile(luigi.ExternalTask):
    filename = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(str(self.filename))


class ExtractRawFiles(luigi.Task):
    scrape_date = ''
    scrape_hour = ''

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(f'{LUIGI_RAW_DIRECTORY}/{self.scrape_date}_{self.scrape_hour}.csv')

    def requires(self):
        for input_filename in glob.glob(f'{conf.RAW_DATA_DIRECTORY}/**/*.csv', recursive=True):
            yield ReadFile(input_filename)

    def run(self):
        for i in self.input():
            df.to_csv(f'{LUIGI_RAW_DIRECTORY}/{self.scrape_date}_{self.scrape_hour}.csv')
```

And so the question is. What is best way to apply pipeline on multiple files.

- pass file as argument to luigi build?
- apply reading all files in luigi pipeline

Comment: Do you want to run one task on all files, or one task per file?

Comment: I think the native way would be to iterate over filenames and pass the names to Luigi. Applicate reading all files would mean that the read-in-task has multiple outputs which is not implemented in luigi.